# ASP.NET Core Self Signed Certificate in Firefox not working

Tags: c#, firefox, asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate

I'm using the Self Signed Certificate in ASP.NET Core with is default on as noted in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl#trust-ff)
I have trusted it with the command `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

In Chrome and Edge, my API is showing 'Connection secure' in green when calling it. However, in Mozilla Firefox (Quantum 61.0.1), it is giving 'Connection insecure' with the following error: `MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`

How can I solve this? How can I configure Firefox to allow Self Signed Certs? Or is this something I have to do in code?

Comment: Sounds like different browser implementations to me, and in this case I think Firefox is doing the right thing. Why would you want self-signed certs to be automatically trusted?

Comment: Then why does the Microsoft documentation state that this should be working OOTB?

Comment: I don't see the doc making any guarantees about 3rd party browser behavior.

Comment: Chrome and Edge (and .NET) use the Windows Certificate Store for trust decisions.  Firefox does not.

Comment: @bartonjs Firefox can be instructed to use Windows Certificate Store with `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` flag, still it doesn't work.for me :/

Comment: It's not just about the Windows Certificate store. The same is true on MacOS

Comment: For me, Safari and Firefox work but Chrome doesn't (mac os)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Firefox browser uses its own certificate store, and therefore doesn't trust the IIS Express or Kestrel developer certificates.

There are two approaches to trusting the HTTPS certificate with Firefox, create a policy file or configure with the FireFox browser. Configuring with the browser creates the policy file, so the two approaches are equivalent. See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl#trust-ff
on the official and maintained docs.

Comment: This is indeed the new solution, it was not documented when I posted the question.

Comment: @Appsum Solutions can you change this to the accepted answer? I'll be maintaining that doc. SO can get stale.

Comment: Fwiw, both approaches did *not* work for me.  I still get `SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE` with both the policy and about:config changes

Answer (score 15):

Firefox does not use the Windows Certificate Store, so you'll need to add the certificate as an exception to Firefox manually.

Start the development server from Visual Studio; in Firefox, goto top-right hamburger icon -> Options -> Privacy & Security -> Certificates: View Certificates... -> Add Exception... and enter the url of your local development server, e.g "https://localhost:4000". Click "Get Certificate", check "Permanently store this exception" and "Confirm Security Exception".

Comment: I followed these steps however Firefox (75.0b5) still gives the warning: "The connection is not secure".

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl#trust-ff

Answer (score 10):

The `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` command stores a CA root certificate for `localhost` in Windows Certificate store or MacOS system keychain. By default Firefox doesn't use these to verify a certificate.

Firefox provides the possibility to trust certificates that are stored in the system keychain. One of the ways is by enabling the setting `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` in `about:config`.

More information: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/setting-certificate-authorities-firefox

Comment: Thank you! That works also for EF Core 5 with .NET 3.1

Comment: Setting just `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` to true didn't worked for me. So I added additionally to that  `ImportEnterpriseRoots` setting to true.

Comment: @yoro - You should make your comment a new answer for better visibility. The accepted answer did work at one time, but not any more(at least for me and a few others, based on comments above). I missed your comment while I was looking at this yesterday, but this was the setting i needed to change.

Comment: Had to restart Firefox after making these changes as well on .NET 8. Thanks!